# Is it worth deleting certificate exceptions if they no longer need to be?

Tags: certificates

At my organization, I had some self-signed certificates for some internal applications. This was causing the browser to show the "This page is insecure" prompt and users would add an exception for that certificate.

We've recently switched those certificates to a proper Certificate Authority and that warning prompt no longer appears.

Would there be a reason to have all of my users go into their browser settings and remove the previous exceptions?

Comment: Have you revoked the old certificates?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll have to look into this. I'm fairly new to the certificate realm. I simply had new certs created and they seem to be working great. I'll do some investigating on revoking former certs. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't revoking a self-signed certificate the same as removing it from each client's trusted list? You can't get the CA to revoke it if there is no CA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason you would need to have them remove it is if there's a possibility somebody will steal the certificate's private key. If this were to happen, AND a hacker were able to hijack a connection to one of your internal applications (with the same domain name that the self-signed cert had), then they would be able to see private information.

Now if a hacker were able to get the old private key, they would probably be able to get the new one as well (if you're storing them in the same place). So it probably doesn't make a difference whether your users delete the exceptions.

If you want to be extra safe, though, you could.